# Crash due to invalid program counter

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

So my question is how do i fix this error. Is it the structure of my program? or how i went about using the registers?

```
#JTWILKI - Just The Way I Like It Cooking Assistant 
# Created By: Samuel Buzas
#For CS2028 Sect.002
.data
    preface: .asciiz "Place you Steak in the oven, and kick back. I'll take care of the rest! \n"
    RED: .asciiz    "Steaks Not Ready Yet Come Back Soon! \n"
    YELLOW: .asciiz "Get Ready to Eat!! \n"
    GREEN:  .asciiz "Were Ready to Go!!! \n Get The Steak Out Now, Before it Burns!\n"
    BROWN: .asciiz "Quick It's Starting to Burn!! \n Take it Out!!! \n"
    BLACK: .asciiz "So how about Soup? \n"

.text
main:
# Tell User the program is starting
    li $v0, 4   
    la $a0, preface
    syscall
# Pause for 10 seconds while users places steak in oven, handy MARS Feature
    li $v0, 32
    la $a0, 10000
    syscall
#Display message,Start Cooking
    j red

    addi $s1, $zero, 150000  # Tihs is 2 min 30seconds
    addi $s0, $zero, 0

    #Start The cooking Loop
    jal loop

loop: beq $s1,$s0,exit  # Exit if t9 == t1
    bge $s0, 120000, yellow  # If 30secs from being ready, print yellow warning
    #Otherwise, Increment
    addi $s0, $zero, 1000
    #Pause for 1 sec
    #li $v0, 32
    #la $a0, 1000
    #syscall
    j loop

exit:
#Display message, Cooking complete
    jal green
#Wait 30 Seconds, then overcooking
    li $v0, 32
    la $a0, 30000
    syscall
#Now overcooked
    jal brown
#Wait another 30 seconds
    li $v0, 32
    la $a0, 30000
    syscall
# Now its burned
    jal black

# Terminate Program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
#Progress Update Functions
red:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, RED
    syscall
    jr $ra

yellow:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, YELLOW
    syscall
    jr $ra

green:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, GREEN
    syscall
    jal beep
    jr $ra

brown:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, BROWN
    syscall
    jr $ra

black:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, BLACK
    syscall
    jr $ra

beep:
    li $v0, 31
    li $a0, 112
    li $a1, 2000
    li $a2, 10
    li $a3, 100
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

Comment: Really new to assembly language so i dont understand the error.

Comment: Would be helpful if you would post the code in its entirety without all the formatting and use comments instead of titles so I can copy and paste it and run it.

Comment: Yeah Mips didnt do very well in the code snippet, heres a pastebin

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mg45rP5f

Comment: I appreciate the pastebin - looks like you just didn't tab it over, but I don't want to assume that before I make the edit. Did you just post the code? If you would like, I can tab it over for you and fix the formatting.

Comment: If you could make the edit and show me whats wrong that would be great

Comment: I've identified that the program crashes after jumping to red. Seems like i cant set $s1 = 150000

Comment: I think you're problem is you used `j red` instead of `jal red` but i'm still playing with it

Comment: That seems to fix the first error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not linking your jump to red.

Change `j red` to `jal red` on line 23

Change `addi $t0, $zero, 1000` to `addi $t0, $t0, 1000` on line 34 to add 1000 to `$t0` and store it.

Comment: did that, which fixed the issue. however, nothing else seems to execute after that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7xAAPy9c     Heres a resturcteured and corrected form

Comment: I think it has something to do with my second line in the loop the bge

Comment: I'm adding 1000 to a counter and sleeping, just didn't want to wait while testing. I have to have a counter to be able to exit the loop

Comment: K well you're adding 1000 to 0 so it never changes - it just stays stuck at 1000 `addi $t0, $zero, 1000` - `$t0 = $zero + 1000` which should be `addi $t0, $t0, 1000`